# Attaching ObservableCollection as ItemsSource of ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, observablecollection

I have an object like so:

```
class RCLocation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
    private string _name;
    private bool _checked;

    public string Id { /* get/set with NotifyPropertyChanged() */ }
    public string Name  { /* get/set with NotifyPropertyChanged() */ }
    public bool Checked { /* get/set with NotifyPropertyChanged() */ }

    /* INotifyPropertyChanged implementation methods */
}
```

Now in my MainWindow.xaml I have an ItemsControl like so:

```
<ItemsControl Name="lstDropOff" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I bind the data to this list in my code behind like so:

```
ObservableCollection<RCLocation> dropOffs = new ObservableCollection<RCLocation>();
lstDropOff.ItemsSource = dropOffs;
dropOffs.Add(new RCLocation { /* some data here */ });
dropOffs.Add(new RCLocation { /* some data here */ });
dropOffs.Add(new RCLocation { /* some data here */ });
dropOffs.Add(new RCLocation { /* some data here */ });
```

The items I have just added do not show in the ItemsControl. What exactly am I doing wrong? Can't figure it out :/
Thanks for help.

Comment: are you not getting rows to display data or you are not even getting rows?

Comment: I am not even getting any rows, I have an empty data template on the control and that stays there, so no items are seen by the control...

Comment: What else do you do with the ItemsControl? I created a clean sample app with the code you provided and it works. Are you by any chance trying to update the ItemsSource from a background/worker thread?

Comment: It is working now, apparently I am just being stupid, I was creating bindings in a function that I forgot to call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set the `ItemsSource` using a binding, which you need to do in order to involve the WPF binding engine and have the control react to data source changes.

Here's how to do that from code-behind:

```
// instead of lstDropOff.ItemsSource = dropOffs
var binding = new Binding() { Source = dropOffs };
lstDropOff.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

Comment: hmm makes sense, still not getting any rows though :/

Comment: turns out it works, but I am being retarded and not calling the function in which I create the binding :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code, I tried using this... and show up on your xaml code

```
using PhoneApp4.Resources;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace PhoneApp4
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<RCLocation> dropOffs = new ObservableCollection<RCLocation>();
            lstDropOff.ItemsSource = dropOffs;
            dropOffs.Add(new RCLocation { Id = "1", Name = "Tester", Checked = true });
            dropOffs.Add(new RCLocation { Id = "1", Name = "Tester", Checked = true });
            dropOffs.Add(new RCLocation { Id = "1", Name = "Tester", Checked = true });
            dropOffs.Add(new RCLocation { Id = "1", Name = "Tester", Checked = true });
        }
    }

    class RCLocation 
    {
        private string _id;
        private string _name;
        private bool _checked;

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }
}
```